# Jquery scroll to bottom of div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll, scrollbar

I am implementing a chat application with php, html, css and jquery. I would like the chatbox to scroll down to the last chat element on document.onload (however this is a private chat messaging system so there will be both sender and receiver messaegs). I already looked into solutions and when there are a specific amount of messages - the div only scrolls to a specific amount. Below are some code snippets. Any help is appreciated.

```
(document).ready(function(){
    $("html,body").animate({ scrollTop: $(".right-header-contentChat").position().top }, 1000);});
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div id="scrolling_to_bottom" class="col-md-12 right-header-contentChat">


  </div>
</div>
```

```css
.right-header-contentChat{ 
    overflow-y: scroll; 
    background-color: #FFFFFF; 
    position: relative; 
}
```

This is the outcome when I refresh:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/60xMo.png

Answer (score 0):

Try this to scroll to bottom

> $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height() }, 1000);

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
     $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height() }, 1000);
    });
```

```css
.right-header-contentChat{ 
    overflow-y: scroll; 
    background-color: #FFFFFF; 
    position: relative; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div id="scrolling_to_bottom" class="col-md-12 right-header-contentChat">
<div><p>hi</p></div>
<div><p>hi1</p></div>
<div><p>hi</p></div>
<div><p>hi</p></div>
<div><p>hi</p></div>
<div><p>hi</p></div>
<div><p>hi</p></div>
<div><p>hi</p></div>
<div><p>hi</p></div>
<div><p>hi</p></div>
<div><p>hi</p></div>
<div><p>hi</p></div>
<div><p>hi</p></div>
<div><p>hi</p></div>
<div><p>hi</p></div>
<div><p>hi</p></div>
<div><p>hi</p></div>
<div><p>hi</p></div>
<div><p>hi</p></div>
<div><p>hi</p></div>
<div><p>hi</p></div>
<div><p>hi</p></div>
<div><p>hi</p></div>
<div><p>hi</p></div>
<div><p>hi</p></div>
<div><p>hi</p></div>
<div><p>hi</p></div>
<div><p>hi</p></div>
<div><p>hi</p></div>
<div><p>hi</p></div>
<div><p>hi</p></div>
<div><p>hi</p></div>
<div><p>hi</p></div>
<div><p>hi</p></div>
<div><p>hi</p></div>
<div><p>hi</p></div>
<div><p>hi</p></div>
<div><p>hi</p></div>
<div><p>hi</p></div>
<div><p>hi</p></div>
<div><p>hi</p></div>
<div><p>hi</p></div>
<div><p>hi</p></div>
<div><p>hi</p></div>
<div><p>hi</p></div>
<div><p>hi</p></div>
<div><p>hi</p></div>
<div><p>hi</p></div>
<div><p>hi</p></div>
<div><p>hi</p></div>
<div><p>hi</p></div>
<div><p>hi</p></div>
<div><p>hi</p></div>
<div><p>hi</p></div>
<div><p>hi</p></div>
<div><p>hi</p></div>
<div><p>hi</p></div>
<div><p>hi</p></div>
<div><p>hi</p></div>
<div><p>hi</p></div>
<div><p>hi</p></div>
<div><p>hi</p></div>
<div><p>hi</p></div>
<div><p>hi</p></div>
<div><p>hi</p></div>
<div><p>hi</p></div>
<div><p>hi</p></div>
<div><p>hi</p></div>
<div><p>hi</p></div>
<div><p>hi</p></div>
<div><p>hi</p></div>
<div><p>hi</p></div>
<div><p>hi</p></div>
<div><p>hi</p></div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! I just had to replace "html, body" to .right-header-contentChat

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function () 
{
  $('.chat-area').animate({scrollTop: $('.chat-area')[0].scrollHeight}, 1000);
});
```

```css
.chat-area
{
height: 200px;
overflow:auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="chat-area">
  <p>Chat message</p>
   <p>Chat message</p> 
   <p>Chat message</p> 
   <p>Chat message</p>
   <p>Chat message</p>
   <p>Chat message</p>
   <p>Chat message</p>
   <p>Chat message</p>
   <p>Chat message</p>
   <p>Chat message</p>
   <p>Chat message</p>
   <p>Last message</p>
</div>
```

You may try as mention in the example. I hope you could find your solution.